# How to implement support for 2 web sites with 1 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

Platform: ASP.NET 4.0, MVC 4 RC, VS 2012

**Update: I've answer my question, myself. Please see my answer post below**

**What I want to do:**

I currently have a site called www.a.com which targets a specific customer segment. I want to create a variant called www.b.com which targets a different segment.

However, in the background, the technology and code for a and b will be the same for most parts, with only some pages / content different depending on whether the user is browsing using domain a or b. It makes absolutely no sense for me to create a new project for this purpose.

However, it's not at all clear to me how I should implement www.b.com and it's flow in MVC. How to render a different homepage when someone comes from www.b.com, goes through many pages which are the same as www.a.com but some rendered different depending on whether the URL is for a or b.

Some pointers, hints, examples greatly appreciated.

**Update: I've answer my question, myself. Please see my answer post below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's what I finally did**

First, thanks to those that answered my post, you helped me think through what I could do. In the end, what I did was a fairly simple sequence of things. Here's how:

1. I pointed my new domain www.b.com to my web host so typing www.b.com would point to the root of www.a.com (CNAME)
2. In my solution, I did the following

I have a BaseController that all controllers derive from, and in there I declared IsPageB

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Base/
...
        protected bool IsPageB = false;
....
    }
```

In the BaseController, I set its value depending on host

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
 {           
       ...
       IsPageB =  Request.Url.Host.Contains("b.com");
       ... 
  }
```

So in each controller, I check for IsPageB

For e.g. In the HomePage, I  simply switched view depending on this variable

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (IsPageB)
        return View("B_Home");

    return View();
}
```

Inside the Views, I either use a ViewBag.IsPageB that I set in the controller, or if there's no controller that's generating the view, I simply set a local variable

```
@{
    bool isPageB = Request.Url.Host.Contains("b.com");
}
```

And then generate markup based on this value.

And it all has worked fine so far, perhaps there's a cleverer way to do this, but for my purpose where 90% of the underlying code is same where a or b, and some output changes, this is fine. But I'm always looking for cleaner ways. For e.g. is there some way I can access the IsPageB variable in a view without using ViewBag or attaching it to a model?

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on the domain name then you'll be hard coding information that might change. Rather than doing that, do it based on the subdomain. You're still hard coding some info but the subdomain way is more flexible and it'll be easier to work on it in development.

From each domain you can then redirect to the correct subdomain.

For example

```
www.a.com # => redirects to site_a.somedomain.com
www.b.com # => redirects to site_b.somedomain.com
```

Then you can build one website that relies on the subdomains (site_a or site_b) to determine the layout to render.

This way, even if the domain names change your website still works.

Comment: And would the redirect be invisible to the end user - i.e. they only see www.b.com/someURL rather than site_b.somedomain.com/? The end-user should notice nothing about www.a.com. From the responses so far it seems there's no MVCish approach to this...?

Comment: Yes you can make it so the user doesn't notice the redirect. But you'll have to do some url rewriting if you don't want that to change. There is no MVCish approach to this that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a solution similar to this in classic ASP some time ago. What I did is a bit ugly, but worked:

- I creted a table called sites with the domains (yes, more than one per site), background, main color, etc.
- Added a column site to the content tables, FK for the site ID.
- Created an admin panel to change this info.
- Created a function that runs on each request (in my case it run on each page via an include file) gets the domain name by `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]` and looked at my table for it. If it find a match, id stores the site config info on a cookie for that domain with the site id and load session variables with this values, so I can use it to query for the right content and display a "different" layout. On the next visit, it checks for the cookie and, if it exists, load this info in the session; if not, load again from the DB.
- If the function dont find a match, it redirects to a "Under construction page".